# Alter and update a shapefile with a field from an ASCII file using ogr

Tags: ogr, ogr2ogr, update, bash, ogrinfo

I have a vector file "map.shp" with a field ID.
I have an attribute table (data.txt) with the following fields: ID, value1, value2. The field ID is the same in both files.

I want to update map.shp by adding a new column and get the values from an attribute table ("data.txt").

How I could that with ogr in command line?

Since I don't have 2 shapefiles (vector layers).

Comment: Are you open to use Python for this or does it necessarily need to be using the command line?

Comment: @MarceloVilla I'd prefer command line, but yes I am open to use python , too. So, please give any information you have. Thank you

Comment: You should be able to do it with ogrinfo and the -sql parameter by using OGR SQL. Read about ALTER TABLE and JOIN https://www.gdal.org/ogr_sql.html,

Comment: Thank you @user30184 this worked using : ogr2ogr -sql "SELECT map.ID,data.CO from map LEFT JOIN 'data.dbf'.data ON map.ID=data.ID" "output.shp" "map.shp". However,  could I define the names of the columns in the output file? For example column CO got the name "data1". I tried to put "CO" or 'CO' in the select option but it didn't work.

Comment: Read about field name alias https://www.gdal.org/ogr_sql.html and try with `select data.CO AS CO...`